# Read GB2312 encoding page using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gb2312

I am trying to parse GB2312 encoded page (http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm), and this is my code.

I am not yet into the parsing part, just in the open and read, and I got error.

This is my code:

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm").read
```

And this is the error:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\x8B" on GB2312
```

I am using Ruby 2.0.0p247

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly *why* this happens when calling `.read`, but you can work around it if you are using Nokogiri. Just pass the file object directly to Nokogiri without calling `.read`:

```
require 'open-uri'
file = open("http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm")
document = Nokogiri(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot duplicate the error using 2.0.0p247,

```rb
require 'open-uri'
open("http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm").read
```

Works fine.

However

```rb
require 'open-uri'
open("http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm").read.encode('utf-8')
```

will raise the error

```rb
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\x8B" on GB2312
```

Are you trying to do some encoding conversion?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://news.qq.com/a/20140824/015032.htm"), nil, "GB18030")
```